# Is $\text { argmax } |f(x,y)|$ a differentiable function of $x?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, maxima-minima

Let $I=[a,b]$ and $J=[c,d]$ be two closed intervals of real numbers

Let $f: I \times J \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x,y)$ has partial derivatives of the variables $x$ and $y$
For all $x \in I$, let $y_m(x)$ be such that 
$$
\max_{y \in J}
|f(x,y)|
=
|f(x,y_m(x))|
$$

My question is if the function $y_m(x)$ is derivable in $x$

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: On $[-1,1]\times [0,1],$ define $f(x,y) = C-(y^2-x^2)^2$ for a large enough positive constant $C.$ Then $y_m(x) = |x|.$

**Added later**: A more ambitious example: Let $W:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a continuous nowhere differentiable function. Then the graph of $W,$ call it $G_W,$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2.$ Now it is well known that given any closed subset $E \subset\mathbb R^2,$ there is a $C^\infty$ function $g$ on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $g=0$ on $E,$ and $g>0$ off of $E.$ Choose such a $g$ relative to $E = G_W.$ Then let $f=2-g.$ We get $y_m(x) = W(x)$ for each $x\in [0,1].$ Thus $y_m$ is nowhere differentiable on $[0,1].$

Comment: thanks @zhw. for your answer

Comment: @MateyMath Aye aye, matey!

Comment: @zhw. Is it possible that $y_m$ is differentiable almost everywhere?

Comment: Great question. It's possible for $y_m$ to be nowhere differentiable. See the addition to my previous answer.